# How to create content type Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I need to add a new content type to the node/add page.  How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should try Google before posting questions like this here.

One of the first few results is the following video:

[Drupal 7: Creating Content Types](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iibPX5KBFu4)

You might find the following videos useful as well:

[Getting Started with Drupal 7 Tutorials](http://www.leveltendesign.com/tutorial/course/getting-started-drupal-7)